# char* versus const char* (Again!!!)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, char, constants

Every reference I can find suggests I can use char* cName = "Some Text", but my VS2019 complains.

I have seen many examples here on Stackoverflow using that syntax and many youtube videos also demonstrating its use.

Can anyone explain why I am seeing my error (See image below)

[image: Example of issue]

Comment: _Every reference I can find suggests I can use `char* cName = "Some Text"`_. Really? Which ones? Maybe, you should better learn from some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/580083).

Comment: It was possible in older versions of C++, but it has been deprecated now. Your reference material is most likely out of date if it says that it is valid.

Comment: fwiw youtube videos arent the most reliable source and even Stackoverflow answers should not be trusted blindly. Also consider that C++ is evolving, so what is ok now may be not ok with the next standard

Comment: @dreamlax -- it's not just deprecated; it's gone. Deprecated means that it's okay, but might not be in future versions of the standard.

Comment: @PeteBecker yeah it was a poor choice of words, I remember thinking the phrase "it was deprecated a while ago now" but obviously my hands typed something else!

Comment: "Every reference I can find suggests..."  Oh my, you need to find better quality references.

Comment: It was only allowed for compatibility with *old* C code. Writing to that `char *` would crash your program even going back to 1994 on a HPUX. Character literals get put into the read-only text segment of a program.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it since C++11. The type of [c-style string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes) is `const char[]` (array of `const char`), and could decay to `const char*` (pointer to `const char`) but not `char*` (pointer to non-const `char`).

> In C, string literals are of type `char[]`, and can be assigned directly to a (non-const) `char*`. C++03 allowed it as well (but deprecated it, as literals are `const` in C++). C++11 no longer allows such assignments without a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Since char* is a pointer to char，the typical way to do this is to allocate a memory and than point the pointer to the memory you created.

for example: in C and C++ you can use

```
char* example = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5); //#include<stdlib.h> required
strcpy(example, "CGTS"); // #include<string.h> required

free(example); //call this after all usage of example
```

In C++, you can used new instead of malloc, and you can also take a look at std::string in C++, it might be useful for you.